# Zend Framework 1 View Helper: if value is not set, return default?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, view-helpers

I wonder if there is a similar method already built-in in any of Zend Framework 1 view helpers?

```
<?
public function val(&$var, $default = '') {
// if $var is undefined, return $default, otherwise return $var
   return isset($var) ? $var : $default;
}
?>
```

and in View:

```
<? $this->val($myvar); ?>
```

I know I can create my own helper, just don't want to duplicate something that might have already been done and [Zend API reference](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/) hangs all of my browsers Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the declareVars view helper to assign your defaults beforehand.

```
$this->view->declareVars(array("username"=>"Not Logged In");
```

If that's not what you want I think you are left with implementing your own, a pretty trivial task.

Comment: Ended up with custom helper.